# What are some good loss functions used to minimize extreme errors in regression and time series forecasting?

Tags: neural-networks, objective-functions, time-series

I'm working on a time series forecasting task, and, in some specific cases, I don't need perfect accuracy, but the network cannot by any means miss by a lot. So, in detriment of a smaller mean error, I want to have fewer big mistakes.

Any suggestions of loss functions or other methods to solve this issue?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could have a loss function with a **penalty term** that penalizes higher individual losses. I don't know exactly how this could be implemented in your case, because I also don't understand how you're currently implementing your loss function and training your neural network.